# Inserting logic to a function or a variable in python (logic is based on loop

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe where I need to assess using different strategies (different rows/columns and different logics like higher or lower with combination of and/or)

I have these function which will run on loop in 'stratr' function:

```
def cf(s):#current
    return df[s].loc[(df['id']==x)].item()
def pf(s):#previous for crossovers
    return df[s].loc[(df['id']==x-1)].item()
def of(s,y):#executed trade
    return df[s].loc[(df['id']==y)].item()

def bs(g):
    if g==True:
        return True
def ss(g):
     if g==True:
        return True
x=0
def stratr(bg,sg,s='s2',df=df):
    bk=[]
    global x
    for x in range(df['id'].head(1).item()+1,df['id'].tail(1).item()+1):    
        x=x
        if len(bk)==0 or of(s,bk[-1])<0:
            if bs(bg)==True:
                df.loc[(df['id']==x),s]=1
                bk.append(cf('id'))
        else:
            if ss(sg)==True:
                df.loc[(df['id']==x),s]=-1
                bk.append(cf('id'))
    return df
```

when I try to run

```
stratr(cf('SMA2')>cf('SMA20') and pf('SMA2')<pf('SMA20'),cf('SMA2')<cf('SMA10') and pf('SMA2')>pf('SMA10'),s='s2',df=df)
```

I get an error ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

My previous code:

```
def bs():
    if cf('SMA5')>cf('SMA10') and pf('SMA5')<pf('SMA10'):
        return True
def ss():
     if cf('SMA2')<cf('SMA10') and pf('SMA2')>pf('SMA10'):
        return True
```

runs well with no (bg/sg) on the function, but I need to have them so I can change the strategy whenever I needed to. I also tried

```
bs(cf('SMA2')>cf('SMA20') and pf('SMA2')<pf('SMA20'))
```

works but again, the flexibility of the function would be lost.

So is there a way in which we could assign the condition/logic in the parameter and run it as is?

dataframe looks like this

```
timestamp            symbol open    high    low close   trades  volume  vwap                                                                                
2019-08-10 00:35:00 ETHUSD  213.80  214.05  213.80  214.05  73  34053   213.95  
2019-08-10 00:49:00 ETHUSD  213.40  213.35  213.25  213.25  13  11917   213.35  
2019-08-10 00:58:00 ETHUSD  213.40  213.55  213.40  213.55  64  19842   213.46  
2019-08-10 01:07:00 ETHUSD  213.75  213.75  213.45  213.50  61  22402   213.60  
2019-08-10 01:32:00 ETHUSD  212.80  212.80  212.75  212.80  5   5611    212.78
```

TLDR:

Is there a way to input conditional logic (with vars based in loop) in a variable which does not result to error?

Comment: Typical [`XY problem`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), ask about your problem, not why your code is not working. You can't expect people to go through 30 lines of code and debug it for you. Simply provide input data and expected output and describe shortly what you want.

Comment: I tried to expound in whole as I cannot explain my problem in a brief manner (apologies). I guess my question would be how can I input conditional logic in the parameters of a function?

Answer (score 0):

the function I was actually looking for was eval(), everything runs correctly now